# operate through nested lists in r

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a nested list as per the following code:

```
cat <- c("A","A","B","B")
prod <- c("prod1","prod2","prod3","prod4")
families <- as.data.frame(cat, prod)
categories <- with(families,split(as.character(prod), cat))
sales <- list()
for(a in prod){
  sales[[a]] <- runif(4)
}
sales <-  lapply(categories, function(x) sales[x])
```

I wish to obtain the proportion of sales of each product over it´s category.

```
proportion_product1 <- sum(sales$A$prod1)/(sum(sales$A$prod1)+sum(sales$A$prod2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with a function:

```
#Function
myfun <- function(x)
{
  #Values
  y <- lapply(x,sum)
  z <- do.call(sum,y)
  #Compute
  a <- lapply(y,function(x) x/z)
  return(a)
}
#Apply
lapply(sales,myfun)
```

Output:

```
$A
$A$prod1
[1] 0.6444069

$A$prod2
[1] 0.3555931


$B
$B$prod3
[1] 0.4644624

$B$prod4
[1] 0.5355376
```

Comment: thanks @Duck I wish to unnest the list so I could have a single list with the final products. Somthing like do.call(c,sale) but it doesn´t work

Comment: Try with this `do.call(rbind,lapply(sales,myfun))` and then transform to dataframe and use any reshape strategy!

Comment: It doesn´t work, I wish to have a single list with the calculated weight per prodct without the categories. list$prod1, .., list$prodN

Comment: @lucas Try this: `unlist(lapply(sales,myfun))`

Comment: It doesn´t return a named list, rather a numeric vector. I converted it to a data frame and it worked for my purpose: